# What are the advantages, if any of grep over egrep

Tags: linux, unix, grep, egrep

I'm just learning about the grep family of programs, and it seems to me that egrep is strictly superior to grep - it can do everything that grep can do, but more. Am I wrong? Why not just use egrep every time?

EDIT: I know that grep -E is the same as egrep. I want to know why grep -E isn't the default mode for grep, seeing as it only expands its usability and has no apparent drawbacks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Technical answer: traditionally, `egrep` used a deterministic finite automaton (DFA) internally while `grep` used a non-deterministic finite automaton (NFA). These days, GNU `grep` and `egrep` take a hybrid NFA/DFA approach.

According to Friedl's book [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do), to discover if your `egrep` (for example) has an NFA engine or if it has a DFA engine try:

```
echo =XX========================================= | egrep 'X(.+)+X'
```

Freidl (p.147) says:

> If it takes a long time to finish, it's an NFA ... If it finishes quickly, it's either a DFA or an NFA with some advanced optimization. Does it display a warning message
>   about a stack overow or long match aborted? If so, it's an NFA.

Friedl describes the NFA engine as "regex-directed" and the DFA as "text-directed". The details of the distinction are described from p.153 of his book onwards.

The consequence is that there are some pattern/text combinations that are matched more quickly by a DFA and some that are matched more quickly by an NFA. Also, the way you write a regex for an NFA can have a significant effect on the speed of matching. Often, a DFA will be faster, but DFAs do not support lazy matching, they match differently in some cases, they cannot do look-around expressions or back-references, and they omit some other features compared to NFAs.

According to Freidl, GNU `grep` uses a DFA when possible and reverts to an NFA when back-references are used.

Comment: In the code snippet, is it supposed to be 'egrep' or 'grep'?   By what you've written, "egrep = DFA", so it ought not to take a long time to finish, as "egrep != NFA".

Comment: I think Friedl means that the example shows if `egrep` in this case (or `grep`, if you replaced `egrep` with `grep`) is using a DFA or NFA. Given, as other answers have noted, that different implementations of the same tool can use different regex engines, the fact that a given tool traditionally used a particular engine doesn't mean that a particular implementation of that tool necessarily uses the same engine type.

Answer (score 2):

The "family" are each just shortcuts to different `grep` options (from `man grep`):

> In addition, three variant programs **egrep**, **fgrep**  and
>   **rgrep**  are  available.  **egrep** is the same as **grep -E**.
>   **fgrep** is the same as **grep -F**.  **rgrep** is the  same  as
>   **grep -r**.   Direct invocation as either **egrep** or **fgrep**
>   is deprecated, but is provided  to  allow  historical
>   applications that rely on them to run unmodified.

```
   -E, --extended-regexp
          Interpret  PATTERN  as  an  extended   regular
          expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified
          by POSIX.)

   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed  strings,
          separated  by  newlines, any of which is to be
          matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)

   -R, -r, --recursive
          Read   all   files   under   each   directory,
          recursively;  this  is  equivalent  to  the -d
          recurse option.
```

Answer (score 1):

`egrep` is just a shortcut for `grep -E` which allows the usage of extended regular expressions. Check out the  man page for `egrep`– it will pull up the man page for the "family" of pattern search functions like grep, egrep, fgrep, etc.

As for usage, if you use extended regular expressions, then typing `egrep` might be faster that typing in `grep -E` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

The drawback to `egrep` is that its regex is a little more complex and less convenient if you don't need the extra capability.  Sometimes, more power isn't better if it's not as simple and easy to use.